# How to use something you can't touch?

Tags: creature-design

In this world there's a most peculiar defense mechanism, just like normal poison once it is ingested or touches you... You are kind of screwed.

But this poison works differently, everything that it touches suddenly weights about 150 times it's original weight.

Exceptions are:

- Air and any gas
- The actual animal that produced the poison

The poison itself alone has the weight of water, but for example if you were to touch it, your finger tip, that finger tip would probably fall off being pulled by gravity.

The poison can be evaporated and then it loses it's properties forever.

So how would someone get any monetary gain from farming those creatures for their poison? This question might seem to wide but it's actually only two things "how to handle the poison without dying?" and "what use does it have?"

Comment: Technology level: it doesn't matter kind of level

Comment: I would use it to make a perpetual motion machine. Also, as described it sounds like amount of poison doesn't matter so just store it in bulk. Also,  how does it not affect the animal? If it does not turn the animal into bags for the poisin.

Comment: @DKNguyen how do you put it inside the machine? And how doesn't the machine collapse on itself?

Comment: Simple. You just put it in. Also, things don't collapse on themselves in free fall, nor do they necessarily if they are small or solid.

Comment: @DKNguyen Argh! I came here to say just that, you speedy Ninja!

Comment: 1. Mix poison into a tiny stream of water. 2. Drop it down a cliff through a turbine. 3. Turbine also powers heat to evaporate poison and water. 4. Recondense water. 5. Pump back to the top with power from the turbine.

Comment: @DKNguyen bad idea.. as stated, apparently the toxin affects the *entirety* of the one object it touches. In you case, that would be the whole stream.  An woe is is if a drop of that stuff lands in the Pacific Ocean! Or words, on the magma in a volcano. It would massivitize the entire Earth's Mantle region!?

Comment: Then this is an even worse question than I thought. You already did not define the effects of quantity of poison which indicated you had not thought things through. But now you completely contradict: "*if you were to touch it, your finger tip, that finger tip would probably fall off being pulled by gravity.*" Tell me this: How do you define when one things starts and one thing ends? What's the difference between a rock, soil particle, grain of sand, mountain, or the ground itself?  The difference between your fingernail, finger skin, and entire finger? Your rule sounds completely arbitrary.

Comment: Apparently this substance must reach certain "saturation level" to work. A drop of it will saturate the fingertip, but not the entire finger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation of [PcMan's answer:](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/194096/21222)

Have a reservoir full of the poisonous animal's carcasses. Then let water fall on it. The water will have an increase in mass and become denser than metal. You can use the energy of the water falling just as you would do in a regular hydroelectric power plant. The animals however are still dense as animals and they will float.

Collect the water from below the reservoir. You can use a fraction of the energy you generated to extract most of the water, distill it, and circulate it back to the top of the dam. Then let it fall again.

Infinite energy with a very practical way to harvest it.

Answer (score 6):

Typical [rubber gloves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_glove) weigh give or take 10 grams. Multiply by 150, you get 1.5 kg. While not easy to work with, you do not need to be a bodybuilder to be able to wear them, certainly for long enough to grab the substance and do, well, whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Not to mention you can just use large containers with max volume to surface area. If the poison only affects what it is in contact with just store it in a container where it is mostly in contact with itself.

Answer (score 6):

## Perpetual motion Energy machine.

Make a big wheel. Like a Ferris wheel, just stronger.
Let's say it is 100m high, that's a convenient number.
Put 360 Lead blocks each weighing 100kg around the rim.

At the top, just slightly offset from vertical, is a sponge applying your MiracleJuice to the passing lead blocks.

At the bottom, you have a small flamethrower, evaporating any remaining MiracleJuice from the lead blocks as they pass.

Now you have one side of a 100m circle that weighs 2 682 TONS more than the other side, on a moment arm of 100m.
The wheel will turn with a constant torque, **regardless** of its rotational speed.

You can tap power from the axle to your heart's content, all that is consumed are micrograms of this MiracleJuice toxin.

You could run a small city off one of these wheels!